# in c++,how to change label text when the finger move on touch screen?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a label on my widget and the text of it is number 1. I want to change the number when the user move finger to up or down (up=number 1 ++ and down=number 1--). this is my code but the text of label is not change but in console I see the value is changed!!! and also what is the best way to do that?(get touch event and know where is the user finger on touch screen)

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    qApp->installEventFilter(this);
//    grabGesture(Qt::SwipeGesture);
    QGraphicsView graphicsView;
        graphicsView.setDragMode(QGraphicsView::ScrollHandDrag);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

bool MainWindow::event(QEvent *event){
    qDebug()<<"event type"<<event->type();

    if(event->type() ==129 /*|| event->type() ==2 || event->type() ==5 */)
    {
        QMouseEvent *ms=static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
        QPoint p=ms->pos();
//        qDebug()<<"point y"<<p.y()<<" and label . y "<<ui->label->y();
//        qDebug()<<"point x"<<p.x()<<" and label . x "<<ui->label->x();
        if(p.y()>ui->label->y())
        {
             goUpperLabel();qDebug()<<"up?";
        }
        else{

            goButtomLabel();
            qDebug()<<"down?";
        }
    }
}





void MainWindow::goButtomLabel(){
    int a=ui->label->text().toInt();
    qDebug()<<"----down-----"<<a;
    a-=1; qDebug()<<"----down-----"<<a;
    ui->label->setText(QString::number(a));
}

void MainWindow::goUpperLabel(){

    int a=ui->label->text().toInt();
    qDebug()<<"-------up--------"<<a;
    a+=1;qDebug()<<"-------up--------"<<a;
//    ui->label->setText(QString::number(a));
      ui->label->setText("QString::number(a)");
}
```

this is my output print in console:

```
[root@FriendlyARM /FGIT]# ./ges1 -qws
Using multi-touch device: /dev/input/event1 (13)
event type 109
event type 68
event type 68
event type 68
event type 68
event type 33
event type 203
event type 75
event type 69
event type 69
event type 69
event type 69
event type 69
event type 70
event type 70
event type 70
event type 70
event type 70
event type 13
event type 14
event type 153
event type 153
event type 153
event type 17
event type 26
event type 67
event type 74
event type 76
event type 77
event type 24
event type 99
event type 8
event type 12
event type 76


////////// in here I touch the touch in top up of label>>>>>

event type 10
event type 127
event type 129
----up----- 1
----up----- 2
up?
event type 2
event type 77
event type 3
```

Comment: so you mean the label isn't changing the text at all? but the debug message works the line before your set the label text? weird!

Comment: yes. I put the console mode in my post , look at it again please.

Comment: ok that is looking good, and it should update your label if you use `ui->label->setText(QString::number(a));` (commented out in your code), if it does not then something else is wrong or your compiler cache might be corrupted, that happens more often than you might think. if something unexpected is happening the first thing you should do is clear your project cache and make a complete rebuild of all sources (just a general tip).

Comment: still the label text does not change but the console text change:event type 129
-------up-------- 1
-------up-------- 2
up?
event type 2
event type 77
event type 5
event type 129
-------up-------- 2
-------up-------- 3
up?
event type 3
event type 129
-------up-------- 3
-------up-------- 4
up?
event type 2
event type 5
event type 129
-------up-------- 4
-------up-------- 5

Comment: yeah sorry it's hard to say why it's not working without testing the whole program, might be some other part in your program where you reset the text of the label or something, you should debug it line by line if you can.

Comment: thanx. I make a simple project with a mainwindow. these is nothing in my project.

Comment: maybe changing `if(event->type() ==129)` to `if(event->type() ==QEvent::MouseMove)` could do. Also you should be returning something in your event function. True to say that the event was handled False otherwise. In your case return true inside the If and `QMainWindow::event(event);` otherwise.

Comment: @basslo: really thanx. this my answer. I did not return anything and cause of this my label does not change. thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What could be wrong :

```
 if(event->type() ==129)
```

where 129 is equivalent to `QEvent::HoverMove`

should try to use

```
if(event->type() ==QEvent::MouseMove)
```

Also you should be returning something in your event function.

true to say that the event was handled false otherwise.

In your case `return true` inside the If condition, where you are treating your event.

`return QMainWindow::event(event);` otherwise.